# MySql: Create datetime from year and month

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) as 'count' 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE myDateTime >= DATE1 AND myDateTime < DATE2
```

-`myDateTime` is of type datetime (`2013-01-30 08:48:13`) in `myTable`.
 -`DATE1` and `DATE2` should be created as datetime also so I could compare them, like this:
  -`DATE1`  should to be created from year (eg 2013) and month (eg 01) parameters, and the day should always be 01 (the first day of the month)
  -`DATE2` should be same as `DATE1` with an added month. (if `DATE1` is `2013-01-01 00:00:00` then `DATE2` should be `2013-02-01 00:00:00`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the date as a number and then convert it to a date:

```
where myDateTime >= date(@year * 10000 + @month * 100 + 1) and
      myDateTime < date_add(date(@year * 10000 + @month * 100 + 1), interval 1 month)
```